# intuit developer create an account request getting error response code 10000

Tags: c#, .net, postman, webapi, intuit-partner-platform

for this we have to create account on intuit
url : https://accounts.intuit.com/index.html
I am trying to get proper response for create an account api in intuit.
But inspite of trying different ways i end up getting error response mentioned above.
I contacted support they say it works for them.
Any modification so i can get proper response.
posted request/response for postman and c#
id mentioned in request is dummy not original.

```
https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/{{companyid}}/query?minorversion=51  
Postman Request
Authorization :    
Token Name : Token 10,    
Auth URL : https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2,
Access Token URL : https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer,
Client ID : ABCD,  
Client Secret : xyz,   
Grant Type : Client Credentials,  
Headers - 
User-Agent : QBOV3-OAuth2-Postman-Collection,  
Accept : application/json,  
Content-Type : application/json,  
Authorization : bearer token,  
Body :  
{  
  "Name": "A 10",   
  "AccountType": "Accounts Receivable"  
}

Response :
 {   
      "Fault": {   
    "Error": [
        {
            "Message": "An application error has occurred while processing your request",
            "Detail": "System Failure Error: null",
            "code": "10000"
        }
    ],
    "type": "SystemFault"  
},
"time": "2020-06-29T18:01:30.262-07:00"  
}
    var client = new RestClient("https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" + ClientID + "&client_secret=" + ClientSecret + "&redirect_uri=" + RedirectUrl + "&authorization_endpoint=https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2", ParameterType.RequestBody);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    TokenResponse tokenresponse = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<TokenResponse>(response.Content);
    var clients = new RestClient("https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/9620826365047887210/query?minorversion=51");
    var requests = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    requests.AddHeader("user-agent", "QBOV3-OAuth2-Postman-Collection");
    requests.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    requests.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
    requests.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    requests.AddHeader("authorization", tokenresponse.token_type+" "+tokenresponse.access_token);
    requests.AddParameter("application/json", "{\r\n  \"Name\": \"A 12\", \r\n  \"AccountType\": \"Accounts Receivable\"\r\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
    IRestResponse responses = clients.Execute(requests);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should implement their SDK from here: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/sdks-and-samples-collections/net#connect-to-quickbooks-online instead of using RestSharp.

I did also an Intuit implementation in PHP and I see that you have missing things like the scope:  'scope' => "com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting", 'QBORealmID', 'accessTokenKey', and 'refreshTokenKey'

Comment: my client doesn't want to implement sdk and specifically wants to implement api.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you are sending startdate and enddate in the payload